# Polynomial Regression - why do Excel coefficients differ from R's?

Tags: r, regression, excel, trend, polynomial

I ran a polynomial regression in R and Excel and have gotten different coefficients, despite the fitted plots being the same. I wonder why.

Here's the R code with data, coefficients and plot:

    `x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,
    26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,
    49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,
    73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,
    97,98,99,100)
    y <- c(99,32,59,50,77,58,8,81,67,12,79,9,94,14,7,23,37,67,65,84,18,99,11,
   12,21,19,4,80,42,53,100,52,4,60,17,2,60,10,0,54,62,22,93,4,90,56,44,41,97,89,
   46,14,5,39,64,13,86,84,88,82,25,31,13,74,5,84,74,16,23,15,12,4,89,79,89,
   73,50,65,0,19,20,63,63,84,66,27,100,52,30,49,92,77,92,45,30,47,95,
   93,52,6)
   poly.model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5))
   plot(x, y, main = "R output")
   lines(x, fitted(poly.model), col = "black", lwd = 1, lty = 1)
   # The command poly.model$coefficients will give following coefficients
   # Intercept 1         2         3           4       5
   # 48.82     31.99951  41.07092  -25.61735   20.797  -30.48938`

[image: R-output]

Here is the Excel screenshot with coefficients from trend line.
[image: Excel-output]

You can see the coefficients are vastly different. Can you please help me understand why? Thank you.

Comment: Bad numerical methods in excel?

Comment: Sorry? The Excel intercept of 78 looks much closer based on both charts than what R is saying - 48. Unless I'm missing a point ...

Comment: I'd like to add, that since R can plot the "fitted" line correctly, I assume it's something I don't understand about their coefficients.

Comment: did you happen to find out which orthogonal polynomials R uses?

Comment: No, I wasn’t looking into it past Antoni’s answer. “Raw = T” fixed the issue. I suppose you could deduce from there. Possibly using Antoni’s link below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

`poly.model <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 5 , raw = TRUE))`

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 5, raw = T))

Coefficients:
         (Intercept)  poly(x, 5, raw = T)1  
           7.853e+01            -5.850e+00  
poly(x, 5, raw = T)2  poly(x, 5, raw = T)3  
           3.053e-01            -6.827e-03  
poly(x, 5, raw = T)4  poly(x, 5, raw = T)5  
           6.890e-05            -2.555e-07
```

> poly {stats}
>    **raw**     if true, use raw and not orthogonal polynomials.
>
> The orthogonal polynomial is summarized by the coefficients, which can
>   be used to evaluate it via the three-term recursion given in Kennedy &
>   Gentle (1980, pp. 343–4), and used in the predict part of the code.

---

Here is a good [reference post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000214/4089351).

Comment: but do you know which orthogonal polynomials R uses? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47628131/what-type-of-orthogonal-polynomials-does-r-use

Answer (score 4):

I have to wonder what use is it to try to fit this data. In the chart below I have added a linear fit (R² of 0.010), a 5th order poly fit (R² of 0.047), and a LOESS fit with alpha = 0.33. None fit the data very closely, and the difference in the wiggles of the poly and LOESS fits don't seem to improve on the linear fit.

[image: 100 Points Fitted]

In fact, if I rank your points, it looks like they are randomly and uniformly distributed between 0 and 100.

[image: 100 Points Ranked]

If I replace your 100 points with 100 randomly generated whole numbers between 0 and 100, I get another plot which is not qualitatively different than the original.

[image: 100 Random Points]

Comment: Jon - I  used fake data. To do it fast I did rand(0, 100) as you've seen. It's not about the fit. It was about the difference between coefficients. I wasn't aware of the orthogonal coefficients and "raw=T" fixed it.

Comment: Ha ha, explains why my random numbers looked as good as yours. The thing is, I've seen so many instances where people have data not unlike this, and they thing a high-order polynomial fit makes sense. I'm glad the other answer helped you.